# How to queue up delegates to be executed in series in the background with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, backgroundworker

From a game loop i want to start work in the background that should be executed one after another but should not block the game loop.

So ideally a class `BackgroundQueue` that could be used like this:

```
BackgroundQueue myQueue = new BackgroundQueue();
//game loop called 60 times per second
void Update()
{
    if (somethingHappens)
    {
        myQueue.Enqueue(() => MethodThatTakesLong(someArguments))
    }   
}
```

Is there a ready made class in .NET that works for the scenario? Or does someone know a good example on how to implement the `BackgroundQueue` class?

A nice to have would be if the class could report whether it's currently doing something and how many delegates are queued up...

Comment: Look at BlockingCollection together with ConcurrentQueue, there are many examples. Start a thread whcih consumes from BlockingCollection, and items to it from your main loop.

Comment: Task<T> and a custom TaskScheduler would probably do the trick if you want your delegates to be executed sequentially. See http://www.infoworld.com/article/3063560/application-development/building-your-own-task-scheduler-in-c.html on how to build a custom TaskScheduler. If you don't mind your delegates being executed in parallel then the standard .NET TaskScheduler is probably fine.

Comment: Consider keeping everything on one thread and using async-await to build an asynchronous workflow.  Remember, **asynchrony is not concurrency**. You can do asynchronous workflows all on one thread, just like you can cook eggs and toast at the same time without hiring two cooks.

Comment: since it's a high performance application and CPU load will be a very critical factor it will be important to execute the delegates on another thread. but as i understand, the standard .NET scheduler will do that when the current thread is on the limit if async/task pattern is used. so maybe building a queue with task.ContinueWith might be an option. i found an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15120092/355485

Answer (score 4):

One solution is from the excellent [Threading in C# E-book](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).  In their section on basic structures, the author makes almost exactly what you're looking for [in an example](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_AutoResetEvent).

Follow that link and scroll down to Producer/consumer queue.

In a later section, he addresses that while [ConcurrentQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) would work fine too, it performs worse in all cases EXCEPT in highly-concurrent scenarios.  But for your low-load case, it may be better just to get something working easily.  I don't have personal experience with the claim from the document, but it's there for you to evaluate.

I hope this helps.

Edit2: upon Evk's suggestion (thanks!), the [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) class looks like what you want.  By default it uses a ConcurrentQueue under the hood.  I particularly like the [CompleteAdding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287086.aspx) method, as well as the ability to use CancellationTokens with it.  "Shutdown" scenarios are not always correctly accounted for when things are blocking, but this does it right IMO.

Edit 3: As requested, a sample of how this would work with a BlockingCollection.  I used the `foreach` and `GetConsumingEnumerable` to make this even more compact for the consumer side of the problem:

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
private static void testMethod()
{
  BlockingCollection<Action> myActionQueue = new BlockingCollection<Action>();
  var consumer = Task.Run(() =>
  {
    foreach(var item in myActionQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
      item(); // Run the task
    }// Exits when the BlockingCollection is marked for no more actions
  });

  // Add some tasks
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    int captured = i; // Imporant to copy this value or else
    myActionQueue.Add(() =>
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Action number " + captured + " executing.");
      Thread.Sleep(100);  // Busy work
      Console.WriteLine("Completed.");
    });
    Console.WriteLine("Added job number " + i);
    Thread.Sleep(50);
  }
  myActionQueue.CompleteAdding();
  Console.WriteLine("Completed adding tasks.  Waiting for consumer completion");

  consumer.Wait();  // Waits for consumer to finish
  Console.WriteLine("All actions completed.");
}
```

I added in the Sleep() calls so that you can see that things are added while other things are being consumed.  You can also choose to launch any number of that `consumer` lambda (just call it an `Action`, then launch the `Action` multiple times) or the addition loop.  And at any time you can call `Count` on the collection to get the number of tasks that are NOT running.  Presumably if that's non-zero, then your producer Tasks are running.

Comment: If you use BlockingCollection with ConcurrentQueue (and its method GetConsumingEnumerable) - it will block while removing.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
void Main()
{
    var executor = new MyExecutor();
    executor.Execute(()=>Console.WriteLine("Hello"));
    executor.Execute(()=>Console.WriteLine(","));
    executor.Execute(()=>Console.WriteLine("World"));
}

public class MyExecutor
{
    private Task _current = Task.FromResult(0);

    public void Execute(Action action)
    {
        _current=_current.ContinueWith(prev=>action());
    }
}
```

**UPD**

Updated code. Now we able to get number of actions, push from different threads, etc.

```
void Main()
{
    var executor = new MyExecutor();
    executor.Execute(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello"));
    executor.Execute(() => Thread.Sleep(100));
    executor.Execute(() => Console.WriteLine(","));
    executor.Execute(() => { throw new Exception(); });
    executor.Execute(() => Console.WriteLine("World"));
    executor.Execute(() => Thread.Sleep(100));

    executor.WaitCurrent();

    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(MyExecutor.Total)}:{executor.Total}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(MyExecutor.Finished)}:{executor.Finished}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(MyExecutor.Failed)}:{executor.Failed}");
}

public class MyExecutor
{
    private Task _current = Task.FromResult(0);
    private int _failed = 0;
    private int _finished = 0;
    private int _total = 0;
    private object _locker = new object();

    public void WaitCurrent()
    {
        _current.Wait();        
    }

    public int Total
    {
        get { return _total; }
    }

    public int Finished
    {
        get { return _finished; }
    }

    public int Failed
    {
        get { return _failed; }
    }

    public void Execute(Action action)
    {
        lock (_locker) // not sure that lock it is the best way here
        {
            _total++;
            _current = _current.ContinueWith(prev => SafeExecute(action));
        }
    }

    private void SafeExecute(Action action)
    {
        try
        {               
            action();
        }
        catch 
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _failed);
        }
        finally 
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _finished);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems like it'd work, as long as you only ever add `Tasks` from one thread.  In the OP's case that's fine, but I don't think it'd work from multiple "producer" threads, and you don't get the OP's desire to see how many jobs are queued.  Edit: also, what would happen if the tasks are done, will the newly-added ContinueWith `Task` execute immediately?

Comment: @KevinAnderson updated answer. It Task if finished, continuation will start immediately.

Comment: Interesting additions, but your `_total` variable won't update until the task starts running, so I don't think that'll give him the number of `Task`s that he has queued up.  Basically, after all that effort, I think that the suggestion from @Evk of a `BlockingCollection` of `Action`s or `Task`s is cleaner.  But others may disagree.

Comment: @KevinAnderson yeach, i updated answer, thx. Sure, it there something embed in .NET that allows us to do same, then will be better to use it, but I not sure that with blocking collection + concurrent queue solution will be easier, but will happy to see such sample :)