# Using Task.Run to start a continuously running background job with a BlockingCollection

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task

I am using `Task.Run` to start a continuous background processing job on a `BlockingCollection`. It works but I don't think it's the ideal way to structure the code.

This issue concerns the line: `public async Task ProcessQueue()`. I get a warning:

> `This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously.`

If I remove `async` there is an error:

> `'MessageProcessor.ProcessQueue()': not all code paths return a value`

This is reasonable because the compiler doesn't see that `getConsumingEnumerable` blocks. Should I use the `async` version and ignore this warning or restructure my code in a different way?

Note: Imagine I have 100s of these `MessageProcessor`'s, I don't think creating a separate thread for each of them would be an efficient use of memory hence my use of `Task.Run`.

---

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Message
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class MessageProcessor
{
    private CancellationToken token;
    private BlockingCollection<Message> messageQueue;
    private List<Message> processedMessageList;

    public MessageProcessor(CancellationToken token)
    {
        this.token = token;
        messageQueue = new BlockingCollection<Message>(new ConcurrentQueue<Message>());
        processedMessageList = new List<Message>(10);
    }

    public void Add(Message m)
    {
        if (!messageQueue.IsAddingCompleted)
        {
            messageQueue.Add(m);
        }
    }

    public void CompleteAdding()
    {
        messageQueue.CompleteAdding();
    }

    public async Task ProcessQueue()
    {
        foreach (Message m in messageQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Processing. id: {m.id}, value: {m.value}");
            processedMessageList.Add(m);

        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
        MessageProcessor messageProcessor = new MessageProcessor(token);

        var messageProcessorResult = Task.Run(() => messageProcessor.ProcessQueue());

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Message m = new Message();
            m.id = i;
            m.value = random.Next(-2, 2);

            Console.WriteLine($"Producing. id: {m.id}, value: {m.value}");
            messageProcessor.Add(m);
        }

        messageProcessor.CompleteAdding();
        messageProcessorResult.Wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the return type from Task to void.

Comment: @HansPassant async void is a bad practice, what a shame to see this advice by someone with 800k points

Comment: Pretty sure he meant without the `async` which is part of what the OP tried

Comment: Removing `async Task` and making it `void` returning is the right option here. `Task.CompletedTask` would make sense for example if this was implementing an interface that requires a `Task`, but here the method signature is in our control.

Comment: @Evk I saw one of your comments about how "BlockingCollection with ConcurrentQueue ... will block when removing" (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41271450/10984827). In that case will my ProcessQueue method block here? Do you recommend an alternative way to structure this code? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an [action block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `async` and write the following at the end of the `ProcessQueue` method:

```
return Task.CompletedTask;
```

This way we solve the `not all code paths return a value` error.

Comment: The compiler already told him to delete the async keyword.  Declaring methods to be async when you don't need await is pointless.